# Selecting Multiple Enum Values when comparing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums

I am trying to select different type of Enum Values when comparing, based on what user selected.

This is my code:

```
    public enum CategoryType { E1, E2, E3, E4 }

    List1.Add(new model{ Line = "Line 1", Category = model.CategoryType.E3| model.CategoryType.E1});
    List1.Add(new model{ Line = "Line 2", Category = model.CategoryType.E2 | model.CategoryType.E1});
    List1.Add(new model{ Line = "Line 3", Category = model.CategoryType.E4  | model.CategoryType.E3});

var   modelEnum = CategoryType.E1 | CategoryType.E3

var ValidLines = List1.Where(P => P.Category == modeEnum ).ToList()
                      .Select(P => P.Line).ToList();
```

The above code does not work. Since I am looking for E1 or E3, it should return ANY items that contains E1 or E3. In this case, it should return all 3 items above because all of them contains either E1 or E3.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If i understand yoyr problem right, my advice would be for you to check into a method called `.HasFlag()`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a bit confused.  I believe what you want is to use the Flags attribute on your enum then assign unique values to them (it's difficult cause your code is invalid).  For example:

```
[Flags]
public enum CategoryType { E1 = 1, E2 = 2, E3 = 4, E4 = 8 }
```

In this way your 'bit or' operator (|) will allow you to properly combine your values (up to 31 values, plus 0) into a unique value.  To test it you want to do something like this:

```
if ((value & CategoryType.E2) == CategoryType.E2) { ...
```

They way you have it your bit or's will return non-unique ints.  What you have is this:

```
public enum CategoryType { E1 = 0, E2 = 1, E3 = 2, E4 = 3 }
```

This is the default enum behavior.  So E1 | E3 is 0 | 2 which is 2.  E2 | E3 is 1 | 2 which is 3, which is the same as E4.